# How to expose port of Docker container for localhost

Tags: node.js, docker, networking, raspberry-pi, localhost

I have dockerized simple node.js REST API. I'm building container with this API on my raspberry. This node.js app needs to be installed on few raspberry devices, on every device user will be using angular app which is hosted on my server and this client app will send request to this API.

I can connect to api by using IP of container which can be obtained from container VM by
using **ifconfig** - **http://{containerIp}:2710**.The problem is that my angular app is using HTTPS and API is using HTTP so there will be Mixed content error. That way may also generate additional problem with container IP because every machine can have different container IP but there is one client app with one config.

I suppose if I will configure access to this API for **http://localhost:2710** there will be no error, but I don't know how can I make this container visible on raspberry localhost

This is how i'm building my docker environment

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM arm32v7/node

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/back
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/back

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/back/

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app/back/

EXPOSE 2710

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

**Compose**

```
services:
  backend:
    image: // path to my repo with image
    ports:
      - 2710:2710
    container_name: backend
    privileged: true
    restart: always
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Your port already is exposed. SSL termination or getting the Angular app to point at the necessary API endpoint? You should be using a load balancer to fix the 'multiple IP" problem

Comment: It's exposed but for some reason when I'm making curl http://localhost:2710, I'm getting Failed to connect to localhost port 2710: Connection refused

Comment: Well, is the container running?

Comment: Yes it is, i forget to say that this problem only occurs on raspberry. When im building this environemnt on my computer everything is ok

Comment: I still dont understand what the problem is since you've not shown the Angular code, and the port already is "exposed" as per your compose file. You can test this with `curl localhost:27017` from an SSH session on the Pi itself (not from your host machine). If you need HTTPS connections, you can run Nginx reverse proxy, for example that does SSL-termination, then point Angular *at that*.